# SWT DateTime format change

Tags: java, datetime, swt, date-format

I'm using a DateTime SWT component, and it has an American format when displayed (mm/dd/yyyy).

Is there any way to change the format to dd/mm/yyyy ?

Comment: did you try with Simple Date Formatter ? post Code where you are getting date and o/p

Comment: I believe the date time format is set by the OS locale settings. (PS mm/dd/yyyy would be American rather than English, the English normally use dd/mm/yyyy)

Comment: The Eclipse Nebula [CDateTime](http://eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php) supports more formats for the date and time.

Comment: @Anand Dwivedi I mean the date in the swt component has the english format. I'm not sure if I can apply SimpleDateFormatter to a swt component

Comment: @Jonah Graham, thanks. Sorry, I meant American :)

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime` [uses](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/platform-swt-dev/msg05240.html) the OS specific user preferences to format the date. (On Windows these are the Regional and Language Options in the system settings).

A possible workaround is described [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248075) (scroll down to the latest two entries). But I haven't tried this myself.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the locale to change the date format, e.g. to Italy [who use dd/mm/yyyy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country):

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ITALY);
```

An alternative is the Nebula CDateTime Widget: https://www.eclipse.org/nebula/widgets/cdatetime/cdatetime.php

(btw: if you are using Linux there is a bug regarding the locale: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=248075)

Comment: " e.g. to Italy who use mm/dd/yyyy:" I assume you meant to write "dd/mm/yyyy" there?

Comment: SWT DateTime does **not** use the Java locale settings to determine the date and time format. Instead, it uses the OS locale settings, just as @wero describes in his answer.